# Creating a megamenu with several submenus and adding a slide animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a mega-menu with several submenus. The animation is not working properly, on clicking the elements in second subcategory.
In my opinion, this part of code is making this bug, but without it the animation is not working, when a click it on second time:

Is there a way to solve?

```js
$('.category li').click(function(event) {
  $('.category li').children('.r_div').css('display', 'none');
  $(this).children('.r_div').css('display', 'block');
  $('.category li').children('.r_div').animate({
    width: '0%'    
  },0);
  $(this).children('.r_div').animate({
    width: '100%'    
  },300);
});
$('.cat_2 li').click(function(event) {
  $('.cat_2 li').children('.cat_3').css('display', 'none');
  $(this).children('.cat_3').css('display', 'block');
  
  $(this).children('.cat_3').animate({
    width: '100%'    
  },300);
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
  padding:0;
}

.category li {
  padding: 5px 0;
  background: #eee;
  cursor:pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.category ul{
  width:100%;
}

.r_div , .cat_3{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width:0%;
  background: #eee;
  left:100%;
  border-left:3px solid #000;
  padding:0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="category">
  <li>
    Menu #1
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul class="cat_2">
        <li>Test
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #2
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #3
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #4
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #5
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul class="cat_2">
        <li>Test5
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test5</li>
        
        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test5</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can animate by adding and removing class and based on class you animate the `width`, `opacity`, `visibility` by **CSS** like below:

```js
console.log($('.category>li').length);
$('.category>li').click(function(event) {
  $(this).siblings('li').find('.r_div').removeClass('slideRight').find('.cat_3').removeClass('slideRight');
  $(this).find('.r_div').addClass('slideRight');
});
$('.cat_2>li').click(function(event) {
  $(this).siblings('li').find('.cat_3').removeClass('slideRight')
  $(this).find('.cat_3').addClass('slideRight');
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.category {
  width: 100px;
}

.category li {
  padding: 5px 0;
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.r_div,
.cat_3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;
  background: #eee;
  left: 100%;
  border-left: 3px solid #000;
  padding: 0 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.r_div.slideRight,
.cat_3.slideRight {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 100px;
  transition: all .3s linear;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="category">
  <li>
    Menu #1
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul class="cat_2">
        <li>Test
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #2
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #3
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #4
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
        <li>Test4</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    Menu #5
    <div class="r_div">
      <ul class="cat_2">
        <li>Test5
          <ul class="cat_3">
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
            <li>submenu</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test5</li>

        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test5</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```